# ODBC Invalid datetime format. (#0) error after upgrading to Office 2016

Tags: sql, vba, oracle, datetime, ms-access

A little bit of background:

I'm migrating ton of Access 2000 *.mdb* applications from an old *Windows 2003 server* to a *Windows 2016 Server* that has Office 2016. The backend databases for them are also upgraded. All these applications are using Access as the frontend and Oracle as the backend.

| Server Environment | MS Access frontend | Oracle Database backend | Oracle Client | References in the MS Access |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Old 2003 Server | Office 2000 | Oracle 10g 10.2.0.4.0 | 10.02.00.01 | [image] |
| New 2016 Server | Office 2016 | Oracle 19c 19.0.0.0.0 | 12.02.00.01 | [image] |

Most applications are working fine but few ones that involve `datetime` in their queries seem to fail with this error:

```
ODBC -- call failed.
[Oracle][ODBC] Invalid datetime format. (#0)
```

Note: There's no such issue while running them from the old 2003 server.

This is the VBA code snippet in the access (*.mdb*) file calling some query that's in it:

```
stDocName = "the_query_name"
DoCmd.OpenQuery stDocName, acNormal, acEdit 'acNormal and acEdit have values 0 and 1 respectively.
```

The `the_query_name` query:

```
--INVENTORY and PRODUCT_TYPE are tables in SOME schema in Oracle
--YING DATE TABLE is a table in MS Access that stores dates to use while querying the Oracle database.

SELECT SOME_INVENTORY.INVENTORY_DATE, SOME_PRODUCT_TYPE.PRODUCT_TYPE_CODE
FROM 
SOME_INVENTORY INNER JOIN SOME_PRODUCT_TYPE ON SOME_INVENTORY.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID = SOME_PRODUCT_TYPE.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID
INNER JOIN [YING DATE TABLE] ON SOME_INVENTORY.INVENTORY_DATE = [YING DATE TABLE].[Open Inventory Datetime]

-- Other Joins here
-- WHERE Clause here
-- ORDER BY here
```

My guess is that it's failing while trying to join the date in MS Access table to date in Oracle table. But why?

The *YING DATE TABLE* access table:

| Inventory Date | Inventory Time | Inventory Datetime | Open Date | Open Time | Open Datetime | Close Date | Close Time | Close Datetime | Open Inventory Datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7/7/2021 | 5:00:00 AM | 7/7/2021 5:00:00 AM | 7/1/2021 | 12:01:00 AM | 7/1/2021 12:01:00 AM | 7/7/2021 | 12:01:00 AM | 7/7/2021 12:01:00 AM | 7/1/2021 5:00:00 AM |

The datatypes of dates that are joined:

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 'SOME_INVENTORY.INVENTORY_DATE' column in Oracle | `DATE` |
| '[YING DATE TABLE].[Open Inventory Datetime]' column in Access | `Date/Time` |
| 'SOME_INVENTORY.INVENTORY_DATE' column in *Linked* Access Table | `Date/Time` |

What I have tried so far:

1. To see if the new 19c database or the new Oracle client has anything to do with it, I used the old oracle client 10.02.00.04 and the old database: Oracle 10g 10.2.0.4.0 while running the app from Office 2016.
   **The error still doesn't go away.**  (Running it in old 2003 server from Office 2000 doesn't throw this error.)
2. Upgraded the *.mdb* file by saving it as new database format of *.accdb* and ran it.
   **The error still doesn't go away.**

Can someone please help me with this? I've spent days on this already.

Thank You!

Comment: What is the data type of `SOME_INVENTORY.INVENTORY_DATE` and of `[YING DATE TABLE].[Open Inventory Datetime]`? Please do not guess or try to remember but verify under Access' Table Design. Even report what the data type is in Oracle (outside of Access) since Oracle has a handful of [datetime types](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/datetime-data-types-and-time-zone-support.html#GUID-789689BF-5682-4577-8ADE-8105C652CBB7).

Comment: @Parfait Thank you for your response. Data type of `SOME_INVENTORY.INVENTORY_DATE` is `DATE` and the datatype of `[YING DATE TABLE].[Open Inventory Datetime]` is `Date/Time`. I also updated my question with this information.

Comment: Thanks and what is data type of `SOME_INVENTORY.INVENTORY_DATE` in the *linked* Access table (outside Oracle). Is it also `Date/Time`?

Comment: @Parfait Hi Yes, you're right. `SOME_INVENTORY.INVENTORY_DATE` column in *linked* Access Table is also `Date/Time`

Comment: A relevant piece of software here is the ODBC driver. Perhaps you need to update this as well. (I don't know which versions are available for Oracle.)

Comment: @Andre Thank you for your response. I tried with both: the new 12c (12.02.00.01) oracle client and the old 10 g (10.02.00.04) client. It didn't work in either cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending almost a week on this, I finally found the issue and solved this problem.

It had to do with corrupted DATE values in the Oracle table.
Some co-worker suggested to check *Min* and *Max* date values in that table and that's how I located the invalid date.

```
Select TO_CHAR(Min(INVENTORY_DATE), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') "Min Date"
FROM SOME.INVENTORY;
```

[image: 1]

After that, it was just a matter of locating the rows with the corrupted dates and either deleting them or updating them to a valid date.
Look at this answer for locating and updating such rows:

[Select and update rows with Date of 00/00/0000 00:00:00 00 in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68381012/select-and-update-rows-with-date-of-00-00-0000-000000-00-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

Try with the correct syntax for date/time expressions in Access SQL:

```sql
SELECT 
    SOME.INVENTORY.INVENTORY_DATE, SOME.PRODUCT_TYPE.PRODUCT_TYPE_CODE
FROM 
    SOME.INVENTORY 
INNER JOIN 
    SOME.PRODUCT_TYPE 
    ON SOME.INVENTORY.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID = SOME.PRODUCT_TYPE.PRODUCT_TYPE_ID
WHERE
    SOME.TANK_INVENTORY.TANK_INVENTORY_DATE = #2021/07/01 05:00:00#
```

Comment: I believe OP is asking on the `JOIN`: `INNER JOIN [YING DATE TABLE] ON SOME_INVENTORY.INVENTORY_DATE = [YING DATE TABLE].[Open Inventory Datetime]`

Comment: @Parfait: Perhaps. Question has been revised so many times, that I've lost track of it. However, currently both fields seem to appear in Access as _DateTime_, thus should be fine.

Comment: @Gustav Thank you for your response. They both are *Date/Time* but the error still persists. Any other suggestions for me to look into?

Comment: It should work, so something beyond our eyes is probably going on.

Comment: @Gustav: The query works if I remove that join. I tried running it from Access SQL.