# Select and update rows with Date of 00/00/0000 00:00:00 00 in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

There are few rows in our Oracle database that have date value of `00/00/0000 00:00:00 00` in one of the columns which is causing problems with a Join expression with a Linked MS Access Table. So I'd like to select the row and either update or delete it.
I discovered that we have such a date using this query:

```
Select TO_CHAR(Min(INVENTORY_DATE), 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') "Min Date"
FROM SOMESCHEMA.INVENTORY;
```

But it doesn't appear in this Select query:

```
Select TO_CHAR(INVENTORY_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') "Inventory Date", MyTable.*
From SOMESCHEMA.INVENTORY MyTable
Where INVENTORY_DATE =  TO_DATE('00/00/0000 00:00:00 00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM ')
order by MyTable.INVENTORY_DATE ASC NULLS LAST
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

It gives me error saying I need to enter some value for the month, day, year and AM/PM, but that way I can't find the record with the `00/00/0000 00:00:00 00` date.
How do I find those rows?

Thank you!

Comment: The old value was probably corrupt, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12456242/266304). There probably isn't a way to determine what the value should be. I'd investigate where the corrupt values might have come from though, to stop it happening again.

Comment: @AlexPoole: Thank you Alex. It was an interesting link. It's a very old database so likely it happened before they put some validations in the applicaition. Now we migrated that 10g Oracle database to 19c and it's being called from MS Access 2016 frontend and now we're seeing issues. Hopefully updating those corrupt dates to something valid will fix this for us.

Comment: Even if year 0 were valid, I am curious how `00` is supposed to be converted to `am` or `pm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer to this by playing around with it a little bit. Just putting it here just so it can be helpful to someone else if they need it.

To find rows with `00/00/0000 00:00:00 00` value, this Where clause works:

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(INVENTORY_DATE,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') = '00000000000000'
```

To find rows that might have more date values like those:

```
Select TO_CHAR(INVENTORY_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') "Inventory Date", MyTable.*
From SOMESCHEMA.INVENTORY MyTable
Where INVENTORY_DATE <  TO_DATE('01/01/1000 01:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM ')
order by MyTable.INVENTORY_DATE ASC NULLS LAST
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Now this also selects rows with `00/00/0000 00:00:00 00` date.

And as for the update, you can use this example:

```
UPDATE SOMESCHEMA.INVENTORY
SET INVENTORY_DATE = TO_DATE('12/30/1899 05:00:00 A.M.', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss a.m.', 'nls_date_language=american')
Where INVENTORY_DATE < TO_DATE('01/01/1000 01:00:00 AM', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM ');
```